# Writing Custom Helpers in Zend Expressive 2

Tags: php, mezzio

I'm writing a custom Helpers and everything works fine.
but I have no idea how to pass parameters ...

on config/autoload/templates.global.php

```
return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'factories' => [
            TemplateRendererInterface::class => ZendViewRendererFactory::class,
            HelperPluginManager::class => HelperPluginManagerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],

    'templates' => [
        'layout' => 'layout::default',
    ],

    'view_helpers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'HelperDatetimeFormat' => HelperDatetimeFormat::class,
        ],
        // zend-servicemanager-style configuration for adding view helpers:
        // - 'aliases'
        // - 'invokables'
        // - 'factories'
        // - 'abstract_factories'
        // - etc.
    ],
];
```

and I have this other:

```
namespace App\Helper;

use Locale;
use DateTime;
use IntlDateFormatter;

class HelperDatetimeFormat
{
    private $opts;
    private $lang;

    public function __invoke(array $opts)
    {
        $this->opts = $opts;
        return $this->datetimeFormat();
    }

    public function datetimeFormat()
    {
...
```

If I use a constructor I get an error ... is it advisable to pass parameters to build my class using __invoke ()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__invoke` is the function that will be called whenever you use your helper in a view. I should only take whatever you need from the view as parameter.

What is supposed to be in the array `$opts`? If you need to inject something into this object (your last question), then you definitely need to use the constructor.
The error you are receiving comes from the fact your View Helper is declared as `Invokable` (class with no parameter in the constructor), so the service manager is trying to create it without adding parameters. What you should do is move it to a factory.

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'HelperDatetimeFormat' => HelperDatetimeFormat::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        HelperDatetimeFormat::class => HelperDatetimeFormatFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

And the factory is something similar to:

```
final class HelperDatetimeFormatFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container) : HelperDatetimeFormat
    {
        $params = $container->get('config')['my_params'];
        return new HelperDatetimeFormat($params);
    }
}
```

Beware, this code is more for ZF3. If I reckon the argument passed to `__invoke` in the factory is in fact [HelperPluginManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/blob/release-2.4.12/library/Zend/View/HelperPluginManager.php), a `ServiceLocatorInterface` dedicated to view helpers, therefore, looking for a service declared in the main `ServiceManager` (`service_manager` in the configuration array) will require an extra call on the `HelperPluginManager`:

```
public function __invoke(HelperPluginManager $viewHelperContainer) : HelperDatetimeFormat
{
    $params = $viewHelperContainer->getServiceLocator()->get('config')['my_params'];
    return new HelperDatetimeFormat($params);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I understand the approach.

The point is that how could the parameters pass? like the date and the patterns ... and not from a configuration file


   ` $opts = [
        'datetime' => $this->usuario['userDateInscription'],
        'format'   => ['es_PA' => "ccc, d 'de' LLL 'de' y"],
    ]`

Comment: These parameters are passed in the template of my "application"

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem exactly, sorry :(

So if parameters/injection are required to use the helper, you need to pass them through the `__construct` method (and this requires a factory).

Anything that is "runtime" (actually everything is runtime, it's PHP :), what I mean is passed from the view) will be passed through `__invoke`.

Therefore, in your view, it will look like `$this->HelperDatetimeFormat([ 'datetime' => $this->usuario['userDateInscription'], 'format' => ['es_PA' => "ccc, d 'de' LLL 'de' y"], ])` (which is ugly, try to set a sensible default from the constructor).

Comment: Also, have you looked at the Zend i18n DateFormat helper? http://zendframework.github.io/zend-i18n/view-helpers/#dateformat-helper

Comment: thank you very much! I'm seeing the zend-i18n and I did not know it existed, hahaha I think it was reinventing the wheel ...

nevertheless the implementation of zend-i18n in my view is almost equal to my personalized class HelperDatetimeFormat and it seems that the parameters are passed in the same way, only that in mine it does not work :D

I could put a default pattern in my configuration file but I would still have to pass the date.

I'm obviously going to use zend-i18n but I have that doubt about how to pass parameters in "run time" from the view to a helper class

Comment: and I say that I have the doubt, because I see that you are a person who knows a lot about php and if you say that passing parameters by the __invoke () method is ugly, I will follow your advice.

Comment: It's not a matter of passing parameters through __invoke that's ugly, it's the number of parameters you may want to keep low. See in Zend i18n how we will use the Locale to define how to display the date, and therefore only keep the actual DateTime object as parameter? `$this->HelperDatetimeFormat($this->usuario['userDateInscription')` is short enough to use in your view!